# How to extract time out of text after specific word in Google Sheets with regex function

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I hope someone can help me with my struggle. I need to get the time slots after each "Text_Text" from this one sentence that is in a single cell:

Sth 03/30/2020 1:15 PM-03/30/2020 1:30 PM;"Text_Text" 03/30/2020 1:30 PM-03/30/2020 3:30 PM;"Sth" 03/30/2020 3:30 PM-03/30/2020 4:00 PM;"Text_Text" 03/30/2020 4:00 PM-03/30/2020 4:30 PM;"Sthh" 03/30/2020 6:00 PM-03/30/2020 6:15 PM;

Desired outcome:
start time and end time in different cells: 1:30 PM  3:30 PM  4:00 PM 4:30 PM

The pattern and length of the sentence are not consistent. But time always comes after "Text_Text" and the date. 
I am working in Google Sheets . I know that this could be done with regex but it's too confusing for me and I can't get the syntax right. So far i was only able to get only 1 slot with split function but this is far way from what I need.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show what would be a successful outcome, based on your sample data.

Comment: Your sample data seems is three lines long. Is this a single "sentence" (as you describe it), or are there actually separate five sentences, each one ending in a semi-colon(;)?

Comment: Edit made, I hope it's clearer now. Tedinoz, do you have any idea how to get this end result?

Comment: what about the sample data is that one "sentence" or five?

Comment: 1 cell, 1 sentence. The data I am working with looks exactly as the above. Only the words in quotes differ.

Comment: How many rows of data

Comment: More than 10 000 rows.

Comment: Thank you :) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have data in a single Column spread over many rows. Each cell contains a string comprising multiples of records that follow a given pattern. 
The pattern is:

- identifier
- date#1
- time#1
- date#2
- time#2
- semicolon

For example: `Sth 03/30/2020 1:15 PM-03/30/2020 1:30 PM;`.

Each cell value contains many contiguous records, but there is no consistency for the number of records that comprise a cell value.

One of the identifiers is called "Text_text".

You wish to recover the time values from each "Text_text" record in every cell, in every row of data.

There may be many ways to achieve this outcome, including built-in functions. The following answer is a script solution. The solution is not as efficient as it might be since the times are written row-by-row rather than at the end of processing. However, some further user development would enable this barrier to be overcome.

The key aspects of the script are:

- `var count =  values[i][0].split(searchTerm).length-1;`: this counts the number of instances of the search term ("Text_text") that occur in a cell.
- `var rowtimes=[];`: a temporary array is created to store the relevant time values as they are extracted from the cell value. Later this array can be updated to the spreadsheet.
- `var searchcounter = 0;`: a counter to enable progressive searches for the search term within a given cell value.
- use of javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to search for the search term, the dash and the semi-colon.

  - `var indexOfn = val.indexOf(searchTerm,searchcounter);`: returns the index number of the search term. Note that the the starting number for the search is set by the `searchcounter`.
  - `var indexofdash = val.indexOf(searchTermD, indexOfn);`: searches for the first dash that follows the index number of the search term
  - `var indexofsc = val.indexOf(searchTermSC, indexOfn);`: searches for the first semicolon that follows the index number of the search term
- `if(indexofdash-indexOfn == 29){` and `if(indexofsc-indexofdash == 19){`: methods of determining whether the hour is between "1" and "9", or between "10" and "12"
- use of the Javascript [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the hour value from the cell; the calculation is simplified by referencing the search index number as the end index, and the same value less "7" or "8" as appropriate, as the start index.

  - `var timestr1 = val.substring(indexofdash-7, indexofdash);`
  - `var timestr1 = val.substring(indexofdash-8, indexofdash);`
  - `var timestr2 = val.substring(indexofsc-7, indexofsc);`
  - `var timestr2 = val.substring(indexofsc-8, indexofsc);`
- `sheet.getRange(+i+1,2,1,+count*2).setValues([rowtimes]);`: updating the hour values to the spreadsheet by row

---

```
function wa140898() {

  // setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet4";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // get last row of contents in Column A
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  // get the data
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,Alast);
  var values = range.getValues();

  // create search terms
  var searchTerm = "Text_Text";
  var searchTermD = "-"; // the first time preceeds a dash
  var searchTermSC = ";"; // the second time preceeds a semicolon

  // loop through the cells of data
  for (var i=0;i<Alast;i++){


    var searchcounter = 0; // set counter to zero

    var val = values[i][0]; // get the cell value
    var count =  values[i][0].split(searchTerm).length-1; // count the number of "Text_Text" vales in the cell
    var rowtimes=[]; // setup an temporary array for the times in each row.

    // loop though the value
    for (n = 0;n<count;n++){

      // get the index values for the search attaributes
      var indexOfn = val.indexOf(searchTerm,searchcounter);
      var indexofdash = val.indexOf(searchTermD, indexOfn);
      var indexofsc = val.indexOf(searchTermSC, indexOfn);

      //      searchcounter = searchcounter+indexOfn+1;
      searchcounter = +indexOfn+1;

      //Logger.log("n:"+n+", next indexof = "+indexOfn+", next dash = "+indexofdash+", next semicolon = "+indexofsc)

      /*
      Calculate the difference between the index for "Text_text" and the index for the following dash
      if the difference is 29 characters, then the hour value is between 1 and 9. The total time is 7 characters (e.g. "1:30 PM")
      if the difference is not 29 (it is 30), then the hour value is between 10 and 12. The total time is 8 characters (e.g. "11:30 PM")
      */
      if(indexofdash-indexOfn == 29){
         var timestr1 = val.substring(indexofdash-7, indexofdash);
         //Logger.log("time#1= "+timestr1)
         rowtimes.push(timestr1); // push the value to the temporary array
      } else{
        var timestr1 = val.substring(indexofdash-8, indexofdash);
        //Logger.log("time#1= "+timestr1)
        rowtimes.push(timestr1); // push the value to the temporary array
      }

      /*
      Calculate the difference between the index for the dash and the index for the following semi-colon.
      if the difference is 19 characters, then the hour value is between 1 and 9. The total time is 7 characters (e.g. "1:30 PM")
      if the difference is not 19 (it is 20), then the hour value is between 10 and 12. The total time is 8 characters (e.g. "11:30 PM")
      */
      if(indexofsc-indexofdash == 19){        
         var timestr2 = val.substring(indexofsc-7, indexofsc);
         //Logger.log("time#2= "+timestr2)
         rowtimes.push(timestr2);// push the value to the temporary array
      }
      else{
        var timestr2 = val.substring(indexofsc-8, indexofsc);
        //Logger.log("time#2= "+timestr2)
        rowtimes.push(timestr2);// push the value to the temporary array
      }

    } // end of loop for this value

    // update the hours output
    sheet.getRange(+i+1,2,1,+count*2).setValues([rowtimes]);
  }

} // end function
```

---

**Sample data**

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Tedinoz, this works perfect when I have up to 3 Text_Text matches but fails when I have more. For example
Text_Text 03/05/2020 8:00 AM-03/05/2020 9:30 AM;"Sth" 03/05/2020 9:45 AM-03/05/2020 10:00 AM;"Sthh" 03/05/2020 11:30 AM-03/05/2020 12:00 PM;"Text_Text" 03/05/2020 12:00 PM-03/05/2020 12:30 PM;"Text_Text" 03/05/2020 12:30 PM-03/05/2020 1:00 PM;"Sth" 03/05/2020 2:15 PM-03/05/2020 2:30 PM;"Text_Text" 03/05/2020 3:30 PM-03/05/2020 4:30 PM;
i get that
8:00 AM 9:30 AM 12:00 PM 12:30 PM 12:30 PM 1:00 PM 8:00 AM 9:30 AM

Comment: The problem was with the `searchcounter`. I've modified the code and you should find it okay now. The script as written is capable of handling any number of events in a cell, and any number of those events maybe "Text_text". Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Just perfect, thank you :)